# Vue mounted doesn't get callback

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have user validation in my component `mounted` function but it seems it doesn't act properly.

## Logic

1. Check if token is exist in localstorage (means user is loggedin)
2. Check if user is admin or staff (allow access)

`conditions`

3. If token not exist redirect user to main page.
4. If token exist but user isn't admin nor staff redirect to main page.

## Code

```
mounted() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("access_token");
    if (token) { // (#1)
      const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
      if (user.type === "admin" || user.type === "staff") {
          // (#2) allow access
      } else {
        this.$router.push({ name: "welcome" }); // (#4) redirect to main page
      }
    } else {
      this.$router.push({ name: "welcome" }); // (#3) redirect to main page
    }
},
```

## Issue

1. If token exist and user value somehow is set to `undefined` user still can access those pages which by logic they should be redirected to main page.
2. Second issue (which cause this problem in first place) is that my user data store as `undefined` which doesn't make sense.

`Store.js`

```
register({ commit }, userData) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        commit('auth_request')
        axios({ url: 'api/auth/register', data: userData, method: 'POST' })
            .then(resp => {
                console.log('regis user: ', resp.data) // data below
                const token = resp.data.access_token
                const user = resp.data.user // user data returned from server
                localStorage.setItem('access_token', token)
                localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user)) //store user data in storage
                axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = token
                commit('auth_success', token, user)
                resolve(resp)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                commit('auth_error', err)
                localStorage.removeItem('access_token')
                localStorage.removeItem('user')
                reject(err)
            })
    })
},
```

`console.log('regis user: ', resp.data)`

```
regis user:
    access_token: "Bearer 59|6qI5MH4AWunf9U5Hx9mRQy5iVdWIuh6Uy2b9YFMO"
    email: "weretg342@ryu.rty"
    expires_at: "2021-01-12 08:37:53"
    id: "c7a2f4c0-e644-4c79-a6e1-5d931d696547"
    message: "Welcome ewfrf324"
    name: "ewfrf324"
    type: "user"
    username: "fsdfg4"
    __proto__: Object
```

[image: one]

Comment: `console.log('regis user: ', resp.data)` does not have a `user` key?

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM it has user id. `id: "c7a2f4c0-e644-4c79-a6e1-5d931d696547"`

Comment: But this will always be `undefined` right? `const user = resp.data.user`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM you are right I should have used `const user = resp.data` instead of  `const user = resp.data.user` Thank you

Comment: your question title is not what you have described

Comment: @VishnuBhadoriya my question was based on mounted call back to redirect the user, then in my issues explanation we've reached to data storing issue which was main problem and has been solved by the part that abdul pointed, so my question title is right, but the solution was elsewhere. Read issue #2